# What were the cheat mechanics Mike was talking about in the movie Rounders?

Tags: dialogue, rounders

When Mike is explaining how Worm has become an artist with his cheating abilities(during the first scene were he plays poker with him), he lists off a bunch of cheating tricks. What are these tricks called/mean? I know about chip placement and signaling back and forth, but what was the rest of it?

> "We fall into our old routine Trapping, even run the best hand play"
>
> "Worm really has become an artist: discard calls, pickup calls, overhand run ups, the double duke."

Kinish spelling later references a mechanic's grip when notifying Mike of Worm's cheating-and was also talking about one of them as well.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that they make their own kind of names for some of their mechanics.

If you dig deep enough, there are new names for many the same move in every county and town around the world...Though I'm not actually sure what you're asking...What are other common names for these techniques, or how they're performed....as in your quote they list off the techniques they use and one can easily google/youtube them...

The techniques I recognise are likely different names for a few *blind shuffles* overhand run ups, and the double duke

Blind shuffles are any shuffle that a card mechanic uses to control and fake a shuffle. This is generally to keep cards at the bottom, or the top (or centre!) ...and in rare cases to keep the entire deck in it's original order. These can be used in different situations, however generally one will have 'stocked' or 'culled' the deck and controlled cards to the top or bottom, faked a cut and then will use a blind shuffle to keep the cards where they are. At this point one can use a bottom, second, or centre deal to pull the cards when required.

The mechanics grip is simply the 'standard' way of holding a deck, four fingers on the side, firmly in your hand and thumb over the top. It's often a 'tell' for other cheaters that the dealer might be more talented than they let on. This particular grip is generally the starting point one learns when following [Erdnase methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._W._Erdnase), and well most cardistry things. Unless one happens to be [Richard Turner](https://youtu.be/TwFIJyWKs1k?t=88). It's generally difficult to tell when someone is cheating...especially since the trivial techniques are very easy to learn.

I would suggest reading "[The Expert at the Card Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Expert_at_the_Card_Table)" or hitting up your local [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfYcehXPSVs) if you want an in depth explanation at card cheating techniques.